# Accessing SD card disk in a VirtualBox machine

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox, sd-card

I am trying to add a hardisk to a virtual box running ubuntu so I could access an SD card mounted on the host machine i.e Mac.
I followed [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/458085/1243862) but there's an issue:

- creating a vmdk file requires permissions so I ended up using `sudo` but then when I try to add this `VMDK` file as a hardisk to virualbox, it says access denied which I believe has to do with permissions because VirtualBox isn't running as root

I could create a vmdk file as root but then I would also have to open virtual box as root which would require a separate login and I don't want to do that.

Any other way around?

Comment: Are you creating the .vmdk in a special location? It really shouldn't require root permission to create a file in a user-writable location.

Comment: it's not about creating a .vmdk file, but adding it as a hardisk in a virtualbox

Comment: The question still reads as though you're using sudo to create the vmdk: "creating a vmdk file requires permissions so I ended up using sudo". That shouldn't be necessary in a write-enabled location. If the .vmdk is  owned by root, there's a reasonable chance that this is the cause of your issue.

Comment: I used `sudo` mainly because as an alternative, I used VirtualBox as root

Comment: creating a .vmdk file without sudo just errors out `VERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: That's interesting. I just created a new .vmdk with VirtualBox in a folder I had write access to without using sudo / root and I didn't have any errors. What's the full path of the .vmdk file you're creating?

Comment: `/Users/<user>/VirtualBox VMs/VM-image`

Comment: Ok, a couple of things to try and work out what could be going on: 1. open terminal.app and run the following command, altered to match your fullpath properly, not as sudo: `touch /Users/<user>/VirtualBox VMs/VM-image/testIfThisLocationIsWritable`. If it errors, that location isn't writable by your user, otherwise it should create the file testIfThisLocationIsWritable in that location which you can then delete.
2. Use virtualbox to add a new .vmdk in the folder ~/Documents to an existing virtual machine. Knowing your virtualbox and macOS versions might also help track down the issue.